# Insert text from one file into the middle of another in a specific place with out losing the contents of the second file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I have a file `Coor.txt` with 4 entrys in it. I would like to take these 4 and place it between lines 40 and 44 in the `Otherfile.py`

But it cannot delete everything below line 44 or above line 40, it needs to nestle between.

This is where I am stuck, all the examples I find either overwrite everything or parts of `otherfile.py`.
I have tried the `import` method but this just ignores the contents of `Coor.text`.

I would post an example but all attempts have failed.

Comment: Any attempts so far?

Comment: hundreds hence the question or are you after the latest failed attempt?

Comment: posting some code and the example of the files would make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
insert_row = 10

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    file1_lines = file1.readlines()
    file2_lines = file2.readlines()

new_lines = file2_lines[:insert_row] + file1_lines + file2_lines[insert_row:]
    
with open('file2.txt', 'w') as file2:
    file2.writelines(new_lines)
```

Probably not really optimal for large files, but for small ones this should work fine.

Comment: Many Thanks Tiroha. That's the one. all the examples I saw that involved "row" I ignored as the another part of this project is sqlit3